# Qualifying a profile

Tags: word-choice, nouns, adjectives, collocation

Which of these adjectives is better used to qualify a profile (the width of an elongated object, such as in *crossing profile*)?

- low or small
- large or high

*Low crossing profile* seems more common than *small crossing profile*, even though *large crossing profile* is more common than *high crossing profile*.

It seems there is some influence from the expression *to keep a low profile*, but there seems to be a contradiction in the way the two directions are dealt with. Is it normal? Or should I just use *high crossing profile* for consistency?

Comment: What is a "crossing profile"?

Answer (score 1):

As you note, there is some adverse influence from the expression *to keep a low profile*.

Nevertheless, in general — and in the case you describe — *profile* (in terms of the dimensions of an object) refers to a size, and therefore it is correct to use *large* and *small* to characterize it.

Don't use the incorrect *low crossing profile* just because other people do!

Comment: What do you mean by "size"? How does "profile" generally refer to "size"? Although I agree with you *in this context*, you're making broad generalizations. Be more specific and cite sources to improve your answer.

Comment: I was referring to the definition given in the original question.  Yes, profile has other definitions to which this does not apply.  My answer edited accordingly.